# How do I set the "Select Precision" cursor in a C++ application?

Tags: c++, winapi, mouse-cursor

I need to somehow set the cursor to the "Select Precision" pointer (the horizontal and vertical cross-over) for a C++ application.

Does anyone know how this would be integrated using the WinApi protocol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere in initialization code:

```
HCURSOR precision_cursor = LoadCursor( NULL, IDC_CROSS );
```

And window procedure:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK YourWindowProc( HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam )
{
    switch ( msg )
    {
    case WM_SETCURSOR:
        // If you omit test below, you will change cursor also for scrollbars, frames, etc.
        if ( LOWORD( lparam ) == HTCLIENT )
        {
            SetCursor( precision_cursor );
            return TRUE;
        }
        break;
    }

    // This will also handle cursor for scrollbars and frames.
    return DefWindowProc( hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam );
}
```